# 'NSError' is not convertible to '@lvalue inout $T9' in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nserror, unsafe-pointers

so I'm trying to use a performRequestWithHandler block on a SLRequest object in my Swift iOS app and I can't deal with the NSError object. This is what how my code looks :

```
posts.performRequestWithHandler({(response:NSData!, urlResponse:NSHTTPURLResponse!, error:NSError!) in
    self.data = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &error)
})
```

And I have an error on the `&error` that says : `'NSError' is not convertible to '@lvalue inout $T9' in Swift`. Does anyone know what that means ?

Thank you in advance.

(I'm using Xcode Beta 6 v7 with OS X 10.10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reusing the `error` variable passed in to the block - you simply have to define a local optional variable and pass its reference to `JSONObjectWithData`

```
var myError: NSError?
self.data = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &myError)
```

That happens because `JSONObjectWithData` needs a reference to a variable of `NSError` type. The one passed to the block is immutable - it points to an instance of `NSError`, but cannot be reassigned to point to another instance, or set to nil in case of no error.

Comment: if you mean the `NSError!` argument in `performRequestWithHandler`, you could ideally declare it as `inout`, but you can't because the callback signature would change and you'll get a compilation error. If you not referring to that field... please clarify